# Launching a dialog from a widget does not work properly

Tags: android, kotlin, android-widget

I have a widget that launches a dialog with two options. One  Button to make emergency call, and another to call customer service. Once the dialog is launched from a widget, and I tap on one of the two option, the button doesn't respond. But, if I background the app and bring it to foreground, then that previous selection of the button that I made gets called. I'm using the correct flag when launching the activity from the Widget.

The order of the lifecycle of the Fragment that takes place when things are working normally with the Dialog is below. The similar lifecycle takes place when foreground and backgrounding the app. Not exactly sure why the callback for the buttons on the Dialog doesn't respond when launched from the Widget. Thank you!

```
OnCreateView()
OnViewCreated()
OnStart()
OnResume()
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this problem by simply using `navController.navigate()`. This allows the NavController to handle the Fragment lifecycle properly and in the correct order.